# Terraform Picking up Amazon Linux 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I have a terraform script which creates a multi container docker beanstalk application. I am using value

`most_recent = true`, But still it is picking up Amazon linux 1. Ideally its should pick latest Amazon linux 2 image.

```
data "aws_elastic_beanstalk_solution_stack" "multi_docker" {
  most_recent = true

  name_regex = "^64bit Amazon Linux (.*) Multi-container Docker (.*)$"
}
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "environment" {
  name = var.env
  application = "helloworld"
  solution_stack_name = "${data.aws_elastic_beanstalk_solution_stack.multi_docker.id}"
  version_label       = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version.default.name}"
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  }
```

Comment: There isn't an Elastic Beanstalk stack that runs Amazon Linux 2 other than the two beta Corretto (Java) stacks.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Below url refer to version 2, or I am seeing something different?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history-docker-multi.html

Comment: Which platform there do you think is Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.18.0 running Multi-container Docker 18.09.9-ce (Generic) one, It do have v2

Comment: That's Amazon Linux 1 still. Amazon Linux 2 looks like the ones mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-beta.html as you can also see by running `aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks --query 'SolutionStacks'`

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Yes you are right, I read some documentation and it says that beta release, So there is no other way hmm, I wanted to use systemd rather then upstat

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have a requirement to upgrade Amazon-linux-2. But AWS documentation is still confusing. Can I upgrade to Amazon-Linux-2 using multi container. I have read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68988175/how-to-use-multi-container-docker-in-elastic-beanstalk-using-amazon-linux-2, But that needs a docker-compose file.

Comment: Value of command is null.
sh-4.2$ aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks --region us-east-2 --query SolutionStacks


[]